# evince was not working

Tags: evince

When I'm trying to open a pdf file by using `evince` command it showing like this

```
** (evince:31541): WARNING **: Could not open X display
No protocol specified
error: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set in the environment.
Cannot parse arguments: Cannot open display:
```

Please give me the solution to work with evince.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`evince` is an editor designed to run under a GUI (`man evince` says `The Evince Document Viewer application for the GNOME desktop environment`), and you seem to be running it in a non-GUI environment.

Either run `evince` in a graphical environment, or, if you're accessing this system via `ssh` (and have a local X server), check `man ssh` and use `ssh -X ...` to initiate your session.